# Can contracted indices be flipped arbitrarily?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

Let’s say we have a contraction of the form $a^{\mu}b_{\mu}$. Is it true that $a^{\mu}b_{\mu}= a^{\mu}b^{\alpha}g_{\alpha\mu} = a_{\alpha}b^{\alpha}$. If it is, is it also true that $T_{\alpha\beta}u^{\alpha}u^{\beta} = T^{\alpha\beta}u_{\alpha}u_{\beta}$? Thanks a lot, I’m new to tensors and I am a little confused in this case.

Comment: Yes, but if a tensor has multiple indices in which it's not symmetric you must be very careful about the order, e.g. $X^{\mu\nu}Y_{\mu\nu}$ is in general $X_{\rho\sigma}g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}Y_{\mu\nu}=X_{\rho\sigma}Y^{\rho\sigma}=X_{\mu\nu}Y^{\mu\nu}$ rather than $X_{\mu\nu}Y^{\nu\mu}$.

Comment: Ok, so you can flip them (up/down) but not swap them (left/right)?

Comment: Quite. For example, electromagnetism has a tensor satisfying $F^{\mu\nu}=\color{blue}{-}F^{\nu\mu}$: note the minus sign.

Comment: @J.G. that looks like an answer

Comment: Also note that this is true for a real metric only; in the complex case, $a_\mu b^\mu = (a^\mu b_\mu)^*$.